# error database "/" does not exist on scaled JBoss app on OpenShift

Tags: postgresql, jboss, openshift

I deployed a WAR in a non-scaled app on OpenShift with JBoss AS7 and a Postgres DB and it works fine.
I deployed the same WAR in a scaled app (otherwise same set up) and it fails whenever it tries to talk to the DB.
The error is: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "/" does not exist

I had a sort of similar looking issue with the HAProxy configuration, since the haproxy.cfg assumes the domain root context (i.e. "/"), but the actual context includes the WAR file name (i.e. "/warname/").  Updating haproxy.cfg to fix the context solved that problem, and I'm guessing that there is a similar configuration solution to connect to the DB, which is in a separate gear since the app is scaled.

Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a scaled application, the port that PostgreSQL runs on it a non standard port, make sure that you are using all of the environment variables to connect to your database and it should be fine.  SSH into your gear and run `env | grep POSTGRES` and you should see all of the environment variables you should be using.  Also note that your host is now an FQDN instead of a local address.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply developercorey.  I am already using the env vars in my code. It is the same WAR in both non-scaled and scaled apps.  Here's an excerpt:

Comment: `URI dbUri = new URI(System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_URL")+"/"+System.getenv("PGDATABASE"));`
`if(dbUri != null && dbUri.toString().length() >0) {`
` dbData = new DbData();`
` dbData.user = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[0];`
` dbData.password = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[1];`
` String port = String.valueOf(dbUri.getPort());`
` dbData.dbUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://" + dbUri.getHost() + ':' + port + dbUri.getPath();`
`}`

So there must be something else I'm missing that is different in the scaled version.

Comment: did you set your own environment variable called PGDATABASE? by default it is your OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME as the database name...

Comment: No. There are several env vars that start with "PG" that are automatically set (for both versions of my app):  PGPORT, PGUSER, PGPASSWORD, PGHOST and PGDATABASE.  The all have corresponding env vars that start with OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_ except PGDATABASE which has the matching OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME. I found (and still find) it curious that these duplicate env vars exist. Their values all match except for PGHOST, which is curiously blank.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQ_DB_URL environment variable may or may not include a trailing "/" (for non-scaled apps it is not there, for scaled apps it is), so appending "/dbname" works for non-scaled apps, but doubles up the "/" for scaled apps, which is obviously wrong. By writing safer code to check for the presence of the trailing "/" the problem is solved.